# How do I search for keywords in Google Docs, and see the results with context?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

I have many documents stored on Google Docs as text or spreadsheets.

In many of them I put little "todo: something notes"

I would like to search though them and see a list somewhere

Is that possible? Is there an iGoogle gadget, or desktop application, or website, or feature on Google that I have not noticed.

Currently Google supports search docs via GMail, and from docs, but doesn't show search results previews. ie I want to see the content of the todo in the result. eg

search results;

```
MyBigDoc, todo: get out of bed
MySpreadsheet, todo: make some money
```

I had a look at the Google docs API and its pretty clear that this would be possible usnig a docs gadget or an iGoogle widget, or even a desktop app.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the context of the question has become obsolete and the question leaning to ask a software recommendation which now are off-topic unless be focused and be detailed., but it doesn't.  Nowadays go to [softwarerecs.se] to ask for software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just type "todo:" in the Google Docs search box. that will list all documents of all types that have "todo:" in them.

Comment: This solution doesn't show the _context_ of the search result (e.g., `todo: get out of bed` in their example).  Instead, they're getting opaque document titles.